# Is MULES the right choice for modified transport equation? [OpenFOAM]

Tags: c++, openfoam, fluid-dynamics

I want to solve the following modified transport equation for the calculation of sensitivities:

[image: https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial%7D%7B%5Cpartial%20t%7D%20%28%5Cdelta%20%5Calpha%29%20+%20%5Cnabla%20%5Ccdot%20%28%5Cvec%7Bu%7D%20%5C%20%5Cdelta%20%5Calpha%29%20+%20%5Cnabla%20%5Ccdot%20%28%5Cdelta%20%5Cvec%7Bu%7D%20%5C%20%5Calpha%29]

Within interFoam, I implemented the following code right after solving `alphaEqn.H` (along with initial fields `dAlpha` and `dU`, calculation of `dPhi` and other modifications):

```
{
    word dAlphaScheme("div(phi,dAlpha)");
    word dPhiScheme("div(dPhi,alpha)");

    #include "alphaSuSp.H"

    surfaceScalarField dAlphaPhi
    (
    fvc::flux(phi, dAlpha, dAlphaScheme)
    + fvc::flux(dPhi, alpha1, dPhiScheme)
    );

    MULES::explicitSolve
    (
    geometricOneField(),
    dAlpha,
    dAlphaPhi,
    Sp,
    Su
    );
}
```

It works, but I'm not sure if `MULES::explicitSolve` is the right way to solve this equation. After a few time steps the solution smears heavily. What would you recommend?

Comment: This is a question for cfd-online.com's OpenFOAM programming forum as it's less about C++ programming and more about using OpenFOAM.

Comment: @EricBringley I try it there but until now I get no response maybe you know a similar forum where i can ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cfd-online is probably your best bet as I mentioned in the comments above. It looks like you're trying to implement an additional scalar transport equation, although it's not clear what physics you're calculating when you say 'sensitivities'.

Take a look at the example here on adding additional scalar transport equations to OpenFOAM solvers: https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/How_to_add_temperature_to_icoFoam 
It is out of date as it is for OpenFOAMv1.7, but the concept is 99.999% the same:

- Create the field
- Add appropriate transport coefficients to dictionaries
- Add appropriate schemes to fvSchemes
- Define the transport equation
- Use the .solve() function on the transport equation